# Auto Layout. UITableView dynamic height based on UITextview text

Tags: uitableview, ios7, ios6, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have found a lot of links how to solve this problem, but it works different if string has different amount of letters.

So the first approach I used was:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSDictionary *comment = [self.comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSString *text = comment[@"text"];

     CGSize stringSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

     return stringSize.height;
}
```

The second approach I used:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     NSDictionary *comment = [self.comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSString *text = comment[@"text"];

     UITextView *tempTV = [[UITextView alloc] init];
     [tempTV setText:text];
     CGFloat width = tableView.frame.size.width;           
     CGSize size = [tempTV sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT)];
     return size.height;
}
```

It works, but sometimes I don't see last words or last lines if text longer than 5 or 6 lines, I also use auto layout that fits my text view to all sides of the content view.

I also want to support iOS 6, seems [this solution](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) will not work for me and I suppose I need to keep calculation heights via code.

I noticed when I debug my code, that my UITextView frame is equal to the storyboard size. So the width is **600 pt** instead of displayed width **320 pt** I have debugged it in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. But even if I hardcode this value the height calculation works with issues in any case.